# Is any $n$-angulated category a $(n-2)$-cluster tilting subcategory of some triangulated category?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory, homological-algebra

Geiss, Keller and Oppermann told us in "[n-angulated categories](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/CRELLE.2011.177/pdf)" that some $(n-2)$-cluster tilting subcategory of a triangulated category is a $n$-angulated category.

> $\require{wasysym}$
> Theorem 1. Let $\mathscr{T}$ be a triangulated category with an $(n-2)$-cluster tilting subcategory $\mathscr{F}$, which is closed under $\Sigma_{3}^{n-2}$, where $\Sigma_{3}$ denotes the suspension in $\mathscr{T}$. Then $\left(\mathscr{F}, \Sigma_{3}^{n-2}, \pentagon\right)$ is an $n$-angulated category, where $\pentagon$ is the class of all sequences
> $$
> X_{1} \stackrel{\alpha_{1}}{\longrightarrow} X_{2} \stackrel{\alpha_{2}}{\longrightarrow} \cdots \stackrel{\alpha_{n-1}}{\longrightarrow} X_{n} \stackrel{\alpha_{n}}{\longrightarrow} \Sigma_{3}^{n-2} X_{1}
> $$
> such that there exists a diagram
>
> [image]
>
> with $X_{i} \in \mathscr{T}$ for $i \notin \mathbb{Z}$ such that all oriented triangles are triangles in $\mathscr{T}$, all non-oriented triangles commute, and $\alpha_{n}$ is the composition along the lower edge of the diagram.

My question is: is any $n$-angulated category a $(n-2)$-cluster tilting subcategory of some triangulated category?

Thank you!

Comment: Under some finiteness conditions, yes. (If the category happens to be equivalent to finitely generated projective modules over a finite dimensional algebra.)

Comment: (Equivalently, if it has an additive generator with finite dimensional endomorphism algebra. All this over a perfect field.)